# Is it possible to do secure sockets (not https) with silverlight 2/3?

Tags: .net, silverlight, sockets, ssl

I need to do push feed to clients (not through polling), to silverlight clients fast and securely, is it possible to do secure sockets with silverlight ?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't checked SL3 yet but you there is no SslStream library with SL2. You could do it but you'd need to roll your own SSL and certificate libraries and sit them on top of the TCP socket that SL2 provides.

Answer (score 0):

In SL3, i think its possible. There is an HOW TO in the SDK Documentation "Build a Duplex Service for a Silverlight Client" which is supposedly useful when you wish to push data to a silverlight client.

The documentation also shows "BasicHttpSecurityMode" enumeration that can be used to specify the type of security with BasicHttpBinding or PollingDuplexHttpBinding(which would used in your case, i think).

Note: Not an expert on SL.